# Fixing Gradle Artifactory plugin publishing issue

Tags: groovy, gradle, artifactory

I have a multi-project build that I am building with Gradle:

```
myapp/
    myapp-client/
    myapp-shared/
    myapp-server/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Where `settings.gradle` looks like:

```
include ':myapp-shared'
include ':myapp-client'
include ':myapp-server'
```

I have successfully got Gradle to compile my Groovy source code, run unit tests, generate GroovyDocs, and package both binary and source JARs for all 3 subprojects. The build invocation for which is: `gradle clean build groovydoc sourcesJar -Pversion=<whatever version I specify>`.

I am now attempting to add the Gradle-Artifactory plugin such that:

- All 3 subprojects get POMs generated for them; and
- All 3 subproject binary JARs, POMs **and** source JARs get published to my locally-running Artifactory; and
- The `artifactoryPublish` task executes whenever `gradle build` is invoked

Here's my best attempt (my complete `build.gradle`):

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
                credentials {
                    username = "admin"
                    password = "password"
                }
                name = "maven-main-cache"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

    version="0.0.1"
    group = "mygroup"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        add buildscript.repositories.getByName("maven-main-cache")
        maven {
            url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/mydev-snapshots"
        }
    }

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'mydev-snapshots'
                username = "admin"
                password = "password"
                maven = true
            }
            defaults {
                publications ('mavenJava')
            }
        }
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject {
    artifactoryPublish.skip=true
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'

    [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/mydev-snapshots"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile (
            'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7'
        )
    }

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from sourceSets.main.allSource
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '1.11'
    }

    build(dependsOn: 'artifactoryPublish')
}
```

When I run `gradle clean build groovydoc sourcesJar -Pversion=0.1.1`, I get the following command line exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\myuser\sandbox\eclipse\workspace\myapp\build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myapp'.
> You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.589 secs
```

My question: **what is going on here, and what do I need to do (specifically) to fix it and get the Artifactory plugin publishing?**

Bonus question: I'm specifying version number in 2 places (the build invocation as well as inside the `build.gradle` file. I want to specify version number *only* via the build invocation. **How do I configure `artifactoryPublish` (or rather, the Gradle-Artifactory plugin) to accept the version I specify from the command-line?**

Answer (score 4):

Number of issues here:

1. `buildscript` should be top-level block, not inside `allprojects`
2. When using Artifactory, you don't need to specify any other repositories except of Artifactory (don't need `mavenCentral()`)
3. If you want to use `artifactoryPublish` you need to configure the Artifactory plugin. [Here are the docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) and here are two fully working examples of multi-module Gradle projects: [1](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/gradle-example) and [2](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/gradle-example-publish). Some highlights:
4. You need to apply `maven` or `maven-publish` plugin.
5. You need to add the produced artifacts to `configuration` or `publication` accordingly.
6. You need to configure the plugin with Artifactory instance you are working with, provide resolution and deployment repository names, credentials (usually for deployment only) and specify which `configuration` or `publication` you want to publish.

Comment: Links to multi-module Gradle project examples not working :-(